# is it possible to 'Increment' a character value

Tags: oracle

Is there a way that I can 'increment' A character ? the below is just a simple example . Ill be using a cursor in the future.

```
declare numb number(1);    
begin

numb := numb +1;
    insert into tab1 (name) values(numb);
    end;
/
result: 1 , 2 ,3
```

I am searching for something for characters where I can have such values('Incremented')

```
 result: A , B , C...
```

Comment: And what after you reached the alphabet `Z`?

Comment: @LalitKumarB well I didnt though about that however I want to use it on few names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way - try `select chr(ascii('a') + 1) from dual`.

`chr(code)` is for change ascii code to char, and `ascii(char)` is for changing char to number. Number can be simple incremented, so `chr(ascii('a') + 1)` returns `b`